# Rotate edges in global space around their first vertex in Geometry Nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes, vector-mapping

I have some mesh edges and would like to rotate them around a global Z, using their first vertex as the origin for that rotation. So far the setup has a couple successes: I can rotate around the correct vertex, and converting the edges to curves lets me use their tangent vector to throw some arrow-like cones on their points. However, you can see the problem below.

[image: attempted rotation]

First, although I can rotate around Position 1 of an edge, there's a jump to a new position. How do I offset this so that the rotation starts from the default position?

Second, the rotation is off. Ideally, it would be rotating around a local Z, as if each edge were an object whose origin was at Vertex Position 1.

Comment: Why are you normalizing position vector?

Comment: If your question has been solved, please be so kind and mark the answer that contributed to the solution as "Accepted answer" so that this question will not continue to be displayed as unsolved. Thank you! Here you can find more information: [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). If you still haven't gotten a solution to your question, please be kind enough to address it.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

You can solve this as follows:

[image]

Here I simply rotate the vector around the *Z-axis*, and then add the original position .

But to make this work and not rotate all points at the same time, I use a selection that selects only one of the two points.

Comment: That worked! I used this and got it to affect each edge with good ol' modulo 2 on the index.